# Is it possible in linux to disable filesystem caching for specific files?

Tags: linux, caching, filesystems

I have some large files and i am ok with them being read at disk I/O capacity. I wish to have file system cache free for other files.
Is it possible to turn of file system caching for specific files in linux ?

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [unix.se] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: I wished to do this programmatically but it makes sense to post this  on Unix & Linux or SuperUser

Comment: This is similar to [Read file without evicting from OS page cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9711442/read-file-without-evicting-from-os-page-cache).

Answer (score 4):

Your question hints that you might not be the author of the program you wish to control... If that's the case the answer is "not easily". If you are looking for something where you just mark (e.g. via extended attributes) a particular set of files "nocache" the answer is no. At best you are limited to having a `LD_PRELOAD` wrapper around the program and the wrapper would have to be written carefully to avoid impacting all files the program would try to open etc.

If you ARE the author of the program you should take a look at using [`fadvise`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/fadvise) (or the equivalent `madvise` if you're using `mmap`) because after you have finished reading the data you can hint to the kernel that it should discard the pieces it cached by using the `FADV_DONTNEED` parameter ([why not use `FADV_NOREUSE`? Because with Linux kernels available at the time of writing it's a no-op](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.17/mm/fadvise.c#L117)).

Another technique if you're the author would be to open the file with the [`O_DIRECT`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/open.2.html) flag set but I do not recommend this unless you **really** know what you're doing. `O_DIRECT` comes with a large set of usage constraints and conditions on its use (which people often don't notice or understand the impact of until it's too late):

- You MUST do I/O in multiples of the disk's block size (no smaller than 512 bytes but not unusual for it to be 4Kbytes and it can be some other larger multiple) and you must only use offsets that are similarly well aligned.
- The buffers of your program will have to conform to an alignment rule.
- Filesystems can choose not to support `O_DIRECT` so your program has to handle that.
- Filesystems may simply choose to put your I/O through the page cache anyway (`O_DIRECT` is a "best effort" hint).

NB: Not allowing caching to be used at all (i.e. not even on the initial read) may lead to the file being read in at speeds far below what the disk can achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this by the open system call with O_DIRECT for the file you don't want to cache file on the page cache of kernel.

The meaning of O_DIRECT flag from the open manual is the following:

```
O_DIRECT (Since Linux 2.4.10)
          Try to minimize cache effects of the I/O to and from this file.  In general this will degrade  perfor‐
          mance,  but  it is useful in special situations, such as when applications do their own caching.  File
          I/O is done directly to/from user-space buffers.  The O_DIRECT flag on its  own  makes  an  effort  to
          transfer  data synchronously, but does not give the guarantees of the O_SYNC flag that data and neces‐
          sary metadata are transferred.  To guarantee synchronous I/O, O_SYNC  must  be  used  in  addition  to
          O_DIRECT.  See NOTES below for further discussion.
```